# ngSelect always return undefined

Tags: angular

I am working on submitting a form using `ngsubmit` I get all the input fields except for `ngSelect`. This always returns undefined

I tried with `[value]` and `[ngValue]` both returns `undefined`

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
            <option [ngValue]=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [ngValue]="c.$key">
                {{c.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

and for form submission

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
```

Could anyone please help me understand what is that i am doing wrong

Comment: Can you clarify why you aren’t using something along the lines of [(ngModel)]=“someProperty” for this select?

Comment: Tried but it did not work

Comment: Are you sure that `$key` is a property of the category class, and that it is defined?

Comment: categories$ is the component property whose value is read from firebase and all the values are displayed in dropdown

Comment: With @angular/fire you need to explicitly get and map the key property from snapshotChanges(). Can you show how catogories$ observable is defined?

Comment: return this.db.list('/Categories').valueChanges();  and if i use  return this.db.list('/Categories').snapshotChanges() the values does not get displayed in dropdown

Comment: Please edit your question with all the necessary information to make answerers able to help you. For example try using a simple StackBlitz... -1

Comment: Please understand that `valueChanges()` does not include a `$key` value on each item by default. `snapshotChanges()` is used alongside pipeable RxJS operator map() to add the key to each item. If you look at your data in firebase console, do you actually see a property `$key` on each item?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Replace `ngModel` with `[(ngModel)]="category"`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="category" name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
        <option [ngValue]=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [ngValue]="c.$key">
            {{c.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It should work. You can try by replacing `[ngValue]` with '[value]`